# Is true that if $V, W$ are vector spaces, then $(V\oplus W)^* \cong V^*\oplus W^* $. (Both finite dimensional).

Tags: linear-algebra

It is a trivial question, I know, but I need to check. My feeling says that this is true once I can take basis $\{e^i\}, \{f^j\}$ for $V^*$ and $W^*$ respectively and send it to $\{(e^i,f^j)\}$ that is a basis for $V^*\oplus W^*$.

Comment: Hint: for a finite vector space $V\cong V^*$.

Comment: easy, thanks!
$(V\times W)^* \cong V\times W \cong V^*\times W \cong V^*\times W^*$

Comment: @GyroGearloose, for the case of direct sum this is also true, right? I can easily choose basis and then dualize them?!

Comment: It would be more correct to write $(V \oplus W)^{\ast} \cong V^{\ast} \times W^{\ast}$ and $(V \times W)^{\ast} \cong V^{\ast} \oplus W^{\ast}$, however. For finitely many factors that doesn't make a (practical) difference, but for infinitely many factors, dualising takes products to sums, and sums to products.

Comment: so, for the general case, where the dimension could be infinite, the correct approach is to take the dualization of sums and products, once choice of basis is not so easy (I don't know to much about the infinite dimensional case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true even for infinite dimensional spaces.

if $\phi \in (V \times W)^*$, then you can define $\phi_V$ by $\phi_V(x) = \phi(x, 0)$ for all $x \in V$ and similarly $\phi_W(y) = \phi(0, y)$ for all $y \in W$.

The mapping $\phi \mapsto (\phi_V, \phi_W)$ is bijective. Indeed, you can recover $\phi$ by the following fact:

$$
(x, y) = (x, 0) + (0, y) \forall x \in V, y \in W
$$

Hence,

$$
\phi(x, y) = \phi(x, 0) + \phi(0, y) = \phi_V(x) + \phi_W(y).
$$

Comment: nice approach! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've some trouble here: "... this is true even for infinite dimensional spaces", so if $W$ would be the trivial space, wouldn't this imply that $V\cong V^*$ for every $V$? Asking just for curiosity as my own memory is too aged to be reliable.

Comment: No. In general there is no isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$. For example, the (topological) dual of $l^1$ is $l^\infty$. The first one is separable while the second one is not.  But I don't know what the situation is for Hamel bases. I would guess that taking $V$ to be $\mathbb{R}[X]$, the linear forms $P \mapsto \int_{x}^{x+1} P(t) dt$, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, form an uncountable family of linerally independant forms.